# std::byte is not member of 'std'

Tags: c++, gcc, std, ubuntu-18.04, std-byte

I'm trying to learn new features/gimmicks of c++17, but then I got to std::byte and for some unknown reason I can't seem to be able to compile even most basic "hello world" type program with the type.

entire program:

```
#include <cstddef>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::byte byte;
    return 0;
}
```

compilation command:

```
g++ ./main.cpp
```

But the output is always:

```
./main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./main.cpp:4:10: error: ‘byte’ is not a member of ‘std’
    std::byte byte;
```

I work on Ubuntu 18.04 with gcc 7.4.0. I have checked "/usr/include/c++/7.4.0/" and header file cstddef is there and byte seems to be defined.

I have also tried to use clang:

```
clang++ ./main.cpp
```

But the result was same. At this point I can only think that cstddef is corrupted/bugged. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: I think that requires c++17

Comment: ^ it definitely does: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte

Comment: One try I did was using cmake (first one actually) with set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)

Comment: @DFDark Did you already try `g++ -std=c++17 ./main.cpp`?

Comment: Now I did and It's working seems like I neglected some reading. Also CMake in previous comment was missing target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cxx_std_17). If you write it out as an answer I will mark it correct.

Comment: @DFDark Feel free to write an answer yourself, I am just too lazy right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [πάντα ῥεῖ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1413395/%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1-%E1%BF%A5%CE%B5%E1%BF%96) pointed out in comment I was missing c++17 compile flag. Right compilation command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 ./main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use clang 5.0 (even with `-std=c++17` flag) the same error occur.
In that case, to solve this you need to upgrade to clang 6.

A temporay and quick workaround is possible (but not recommanded since it plays with `std` namespace), it could be something like:

```
#if defined(__clang__) && __cplusplus >= 201703L && __clang_major__ < 6
// This is a minimal workaround for clang 5.0 with missing std::byte type
namespace std {
enum class byte : unsigned char {};
}
#endif
```

Comment: It's a reasonable workaround for a personal project, but still, it should come with a warning: "_It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions ..._".

Comment: Good remark. I'm perfectly aware that it is only a workaround not a *good* solution. In that case, it was to illustrate that sometimes even with a proper C++17 flag, the same problem can occur. I will reword my answer to remove this ambiguity.